# Call or cancel timer event angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I basically have a class that should subscribe to `commModel.sessionState$` and if `isValid` is true it should cancel the timer and recreate it again. The problem is that when the timer fires I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setSessionState' of undefined`, but when debugging in the constructor `commModel` is OK. Also the console.log in the subscribe does not execute. Where is the problem and how can I fix it ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModel } from '../core/store/common.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publish';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

@Injectable()
export class SessionTimeoutHandler {

  sessionState: Observable<boolean>;
  timeoutCountdown$: Observable<boolean>;

  timer: any;

  constructor(private commModel: CommonModel) {
    this.sessionState = commModel.sessionState$;
    this.sessionState.subscribe(
      isValid => {
        console.log('test',isValid);
        if(isValid) {
          clearTimeout(this.timer);
          this.timer = setTimeout(this.invalidateSessionState, 5 * 1000);
        }
      }
    )

    this.timer = setTimeout(this.invalidateSessionState, 5 * 1000);
  }

  invalidateSessionState() {
    this.commModel.setSessionState(false);
  }

}
```

Comment: I assume for `setTimeout()` you should use `clearTimeout(this.timer);`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, sorry just saw that, but that doesn't help with the undefined error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` needs some special attention by using `bind`:

```
this.timer = setTimeout(this.invalidateSessionState.bind(this), 5 * 1000);
```

or arrow functions

```
this.timer = setTimeout(() => this.invalidateSessionState(), 5 * 1000);
```